# Problems while creating a City using the OpenStreetMap maps

Tags: python, modeling, mesh

I've found this blender tutorial :

[How to Create a City Covered with Fog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R1ROxTnD3E0)

and I've tried to do it. And then I've chosen the map of the city where I live and I have selected a small area,but when I have imported it in blender I have seen that something hasn't worked correctly. Please check the screenshots attached to understand better where could be the problem,thanks.

[image: pic 1] 
[image: pic 2]

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you missing some buildings? As far as I can see from the screenshots, all the buildings from the map (dark brown areas) were correctly imported into Blender. In the rest of the map there are no buildings marked, so there is nothing to import.

Comment: this has nothing to do with blender , It has to do with an external program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenStreetMaps only the buildings in dark brown have had their shapes made available for blender. This means that what you are experiencing is normal. If you would like more buildings, select a different area of your city, preferably with more details.

[Edit by Brasshat] Or create the bit of the city you want, and use Blender to add the buidings not provided by OSM.

Comment: Are there shapes available for the google maps or some other kind of map ? This method make easier and faster building big cities. Do it by hand takes too much time...

Comment: I believe there are for Google. I would do it by hand though. Import the map as an image, and just extrude vertexes to the corners of each building. When the shape is complete, fill it and extrude.